# Pass an object(.net or json object) as input parametres of postgresql function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have just started learning postgresql, i want to send a c# object as a parameter for the function(storedprocedure) of postgresql.

i.e. assume that i have a class named userdetails with fields like username,password,DOB etc,

how can i directly send this object to the function and retrieve each field from the object before inserting into the respective columns of the desired table?

Comment: if you want to pass json to function as argument, just do it?..

Comment: @vao tsun how do i accomplish that and  insert data into respective columns of the table? an example would be great to give me a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is example of function taking json as argument:

```
create or replace function works_with_json(_j IN json) returns boolean as
$$
declare
begin
    raise info '%', 'a = "'||(_j->>'a')||'"';
    raise info '%', 'b = "'||(_j->>'b')||'"';
    return _j->>'c';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select works_with_json ('{"a":"Some string","b":9, "c": true}');
```